# Dart List.length wrong value after using split on io.File readAsString

Tags: flutter, list, dart, file, io

After readAsString an io.File, split it into lines and iter through the List with a for loop using List.length, the length value ist most often too low or even zero.
So that I have to use a workaround to get it -seemingly- right but it doesn`t solve the question what is going wrong.

Extremly unstable version:

```
static Future<int> open() async {
    io.File handle = await ModelHandle.alias;
    String string = await handle.readAsString();
    List<String> lines = string.split('\n');
    for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){ // length often too low or even zero
        // do some stuff
    }
}
```

Workaround:

```
static Future<bool> open() async {
    io.File handle = await ModelHandle.alias;
    String string = await handle.readAsString();
    List<String> lines = string.split('\n');
    int i = -1;
    String l;
    while (true) { // works fine
        try {
            l = lines[++i];
        } catch (e) {
            break;
        }
        // do some stuff
    }
}
```

What is going wrong in the unstable version and why do I need that workaround?

Source of the file handle

```
static Future<io.File> fileHandle(String filename) async {
    io.Directory appDir = await pathProvider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    List<String> parts = [appDir.path, ...localPath, filename];
    io.File file = await io.File(parts.join(path.separator)).create(recursive: true);
    return file;
}
```

Comment: use `LineSplitter` - for example: `handle .openRead() 
 .transform(utf8.decoder) .transform(LineSplitter()) .listen((line) => print('line: $line'))`

Comment: Consider using the built in `readAsLines` method: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.6/dart-io/File/readAsLinesSync.html Also, don't build paths yourself - use the `path` package: https://pub.dev/packages/path

Answer (score 1):

If your file is UTF8, you need to decode it and then use the `LineSplitter` as can be seen in the [documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.6/dart-io/File-class.html):

```
final lines = await file.openRead()
                        .transform(utf8.decoder) 
                        .transform(LineSplitter())
                        .toList();
```

Comment: Well, I wonder because Dart says readAsString uses utf8 by default: "Future<String> readAsString({Encoding encoding = utf8})" and:  "Returns a Future<String> that completes with the string once the file contents has been read."

Comment: @Steffomio he uses `openRead()` and not `readAsString()`